# wxWidgets: wxStyledTextCtrl - Colours

Tags: c++, background, character

Using wxWidgets wxStyledTextCtrl I cannot find a way of having the color behind the text to be anything but white.  I can change the editor's background but typing in text results in black text with a white background behind the characters.

Searches and review of Scintilla's and wxWidgets docs has revealed nothing to me yet.  Any suggestions? (C++, Linux Mint)

update #1: After poking around in the wxWidget source, as a test, I modified in PlatWX.cpp the SurfaceImpl::DrawTextTransparent.  I added a call to set brush colour and changed hdc->SetBackgroundMode( wxBRUSHSTYLE_TRANSPARENT ) to wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID.

These seems to work reasonably well.  However, there are added problems with whitespace.  The first being the settings for white space coloring seem to be ignored.  The second is a carriage return always leaves a white blank space and multiple spaces having a growing white bow (as on a ship) when holding the spacebar down.